# How to automate ports installation by selecting all options in "make config"?

Tags: makefile, freebsd, ports

I want to automate installation of ports in my FreeBSD environment. Usually I take the default settings but for some ports I want to -automatically- select all options.

Is it possible to do something like

```
/usr/ports/.../> make config
/usr/ports/.../> ** select all options **
/usr/ports/.../> make clean install BATCH=yes
```

in a script?

Comment: `pkg install ...` and maybe you're better off at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @pmg: `pkg install` only adds *packages*, which are generally built with the default options.

Comment: Oops! I misread the "select all options" as "accept all options".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic way to do that. The whole point of the config system is to make the operator choose which options to pick.

And since the ports system now also supports multiple choice options, you cannot always select *all* options. From `/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.options.mk`:

```
# OPTIONS_SINGLE    - List of single-choice grouped options: 1 and
#                     only 1 among N
# OPTIONS_RADIO     - List of radio-choice grouped options: 0 or 1
#                     among N
# OPTIONS_MULTI     - List of multiple-choice grouped options: at
#                     least 1 among N
# OPTIONS_GROUP     - List of group-choice grouped options: 0 or
#                     more among N
```

However, the options once set remain valid until a port update changes the names or number of options. So in general you don't have re-run `make config` for every build.

One thing you could try is to generate the necessary `/var/db/*/options` files (with the latest port revision in `_OPTIONS_READ`) yourself *before* calling `make install clean`.
This depends on correctly parsing the port's Makefile. And which option are you going to pick in an OPTIONS_SINGLE?

**Note**: You can define `BATCH` when calling `make` to build a port. This should skip those ports which require interaction. But if I'm reading `/usr/ports/Mk/bsd.port.mk` correctly, it will build the ports with the default settings.